# EF 6.02 Error generating Model

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

The below SQL scripts are for 2 related tables. When I try to generate an EF Model (EF 6.02), I get the following error:

Error 13101: The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'from_party_id' on entity 'agreements' does not match the type of property 'to_role_type_code' on entity 'party_relationships' in the referential constraint 'AGREE_PR_FK'.

First Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[party_relationships](
    [to_party_id] [numeric](8, 0) NOT NULL,
    [to_role_type_code] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [from_party_id] [numeric](8, 0) NOT NULL,
    [from_role_type_code] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [from_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [priority_code] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [status_code] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [thru_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [pr_comment] [varchar](240) NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PR_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
   [to_party_id] ASC,
   [from_party_id] ASC,
   [to_role_type_code] ASC,
   [from_role_type_code] ASC,
   [from_date] ASC

 ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,  ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] 
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Second Table

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[agreements](

   [agreement_id] [numeric](8, 0) NOT NULL,
   [agreement_type_code] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
   [to_party_id] [numeric](8, 0) NOT NULL,
   [from_party_id] [numeric](8, 0) NOT NULL,
   [pr_from_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
   [from_role_type_code] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
   [to_role_type_code] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
   [agreement_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
   [from_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
   [thru_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
   [description] [varchar](240) NOT NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [AGREE_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
  [agreement_id] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,  ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] 
 ) ON
```

[PRIMARY]

The 'AGREE_PR_FK' constraint is defined as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[agreements]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [AGREE_PR_FK] FOREIGN KEY([to_party_id], [from_party_id], [to_role_type_code], [from_role_type_code], [pr_from_date])
REFERENCES [dbo].[party_relationships] ([to_party_id], [from_party_id], [to_role_type_code], [from_role_type_code], [from_date])
```

It appears that EF is trying to march the related columns out of sequence. Or is there something I am missing!

I am using SQL Server 2012 and VS 2013 Ultimate on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in EF6.0.2 tooling so you need to reinstall tooling. You can get the version that contains the fix from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762)